# Recovering from process being killed by android

Tags: android, process, background, kill

In the logcat i can see the following line:

03-16 10:10:44.208      748-839/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process MyProcess (pid 30657) has died

It's not the only process that was killed, something is probably happening...

The application i'm working on is actually doing its important part when operating on the background and everything stops at this moment, i would like it to keep on running. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a service to perform those important task and start the service in foreground using [Service.startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) method.

Comment: Thanks, i actually used a service and the Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT flag.

Comment: Perhaps it will save people some time, although the flag i mentioned above suppose to restart the service after it closes for any reason, the OS set a timer for a HUGE amount of time (hours later... it was logged) The only working solution was StinePike's which will start the service in the foregrounds, and will display a notification at all times.